# Unable to review in the Reopen queue

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review-queues

When I try to review in the [Reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/) right now, I get a popup that says

> An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.

This happened as I was reviewing posts, and had just reviewed 7. The same thing happened to me yesterday, after reviewing 9 posts in this queue.

I asked about this in chat when it happened yesterday, and another user [mentioned](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52920630) that it happened to them as well, potentially in different queues, sporadically. I haven't had issues with any of the other queues though, so it may not be related.

This may have something to do with the [recent changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013), but I haven't tried this out on other sites anyway, so I'm reporting it here.

Comment: I was getting this message again (sporadically) today, and *only* in the "Reopen" queue. In every case, just re-clicking the last button ("Skip" or "Submit", usually) generally resolved the issue after one or two attempts. Similar stuff has been reported before and, IIRC, staff replied, saying it was something to do with something in the something-or-other.

Comment: @AdrianMole Clicking "Skip" or "Submit" shows me the same thing; I tried clicking them a lot. I just tried opening up a random completed review, and clicking on "Next task", and I see the same thing.

Comment: I've been getting this pretty consistently for the last few hours, only in the reopen queue. Skipping doesn't help; I get the same message and I don't get a new post to review.

Comment: I have tried to repro this my going to reopen and skipping lots of items (interspersed with other actions). Anyone have a formula for reliably reproducing this?

Comment: @YaakovEllis I don't, unfortunately. BTW, yesterday I actually got to do quite a few reviews before I got a "review queue is empty" message, which is odd for the reopen queue (but not impossible, I've heard). I haven't hit the review queues yet today but will in a couple of hours, and I'll leave a comment here if anything untoward happens. Not that I know how to repro the issue, but I'll see if I can spot some pattern.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I just tried reviewing in the reopen queue, and after 22 items I got "This queue has been cleared!" I don't know if this is a bug, or if it's related to the issue in the question, but I feel this shouldn't happen. I don't have any filters turned on in the queue, and the queue can't be empty.

Comment: Not sure if it's related but, for a few days now, I've noticed a significant delay between reviews in the Reopen queue. Almost like the system is looking for something  but can't quite find it?

Comment: Update: The reopen queue being empty is not a bug, it seems the queue is actually getting cleared regularly, so ignore that part. And I've not had the issue of being stuck in the reopen queue for a couple of days, so maybe the bug was transitory/resolved.

Comment: Marking this as no-repro. If someone sees it again, let me know please.